# setText function in java

Tags: java, android

I tried setText 3 diff ways

1. setText(score)  //where score is int

   Result: My app crashed
2. setText(""+score)

   Result: App worked
3. setText(String.valueOf(score))

   Result: App worked

can i say that setText function only accept char or string value and  ""+score is converting score it into string.

Comment: Use `score.toString()`

Answer (score 1):

You are right! setText() takes a CharSequence. Thats the reaso why setText(score) is not working.

Answer (score 1):

From [TextView | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)),

> **-setText-**
>
> **void setText (int resid);**
>
> Sets the text to be displayed using a string resource identifier.
>
> **void setText (CharSequence text);**
>
> Sets the text to be displayed.
>
> **void setText (char[ ] text, 
>                   int start, 
>                   int len);**
>
> Sets the TextView to display the specified slice of the specified char array.
>
> - start - **int**: start index in the char array
> - len   - **int**: length of char count after start

So in your case,

1. App Crashed because Android looked for the Resource with the ID Number as `score`. Since it couldn't find any Resource with that ID it crashed. See [String Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) Guide for more info.
2. `score` was appended to "" or Empty String and then displayed. When you use `+`, `score` is converted to `String` and then concatenated. So app words fine as `void setText (CharSequence text);` is a valid funtion call.
3. App works fine as you are passing the `String` value of `Integer` directly. Same case as above, `void setText (CharSequence text);` is a valid funtion call.

Hope this detailed explanation gives you better insight.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for App crash is,

If you set a TextView to an int, it will be interpreted as an Android resource id. If you want the value of the int as your text (and not the resource it points to), make it a String as like 2nd and 3rd.